# Формат поля src у img

Tags: html

Здравствуйте!
Встретил конструкцию вида

```
<img src="//domain.tld/image.ext" />
```

насколько она правильная? Если честно, первый раз вижу абсолютную ссылку без указания протокола. Будет ли это корректно работать везде?

Comment: На эту фишку я обратил внимание у ссылок Яндекса. И уже после, заметил в [описаниях стандарта][1]:

> "//g"           =  "http://g"

Т.е. это как бы нормальная практика.

   [1]:http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-5.4.1

Comment: именно тождественное равенство или подставляется текущий протокол (http/https)?

Comment: На форумах народ пишет:

> Это удобно и для http и для https.
> Какой текущий протокол на странице, с
> таким протоколом и будет запрос.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нормальная практика.

Подставляется текущий протокол

т.е если вы находитесь на http - то будет http, если https - то https и т.д